# How to download image from .shtml using java?

Tags: java, screen-scraping

I have a problem with downloading images from web-pages using java - it all works fine except for .shtml pages. Any idea? I can get the page's source but cannot download images from it. Thanks for all opinions in advance.

Comment: how about you post the code you have

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by downloading using java. Show us your code, esp. the one that doesn't work. Could you put together a short example?

Comment: Its hard to tell without knowing what libraries you're using to do the page and image downloading.  Could you give us an example of the code you're trying to use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The shtml extension won't effect how you download the data. It just indicates that the webpage has server side included content.

There must be something else with the webpage that is tripping your up, unrelated to the extension. What this is can't be determined from the amount of information provided.